# How to we convert a cell array which is in a struct array into a table

Tags: matlab

I have a structured array (1*1502) named `summary` in which there is a cell array with field names results that has the following data:

```
[1,114,3,170686,1990;2,74,13,5668167,1997]
[1,91,1,96400,2011;2,108,1,1218510,2012]
[1,17314,3,951029,1998;2,62,1,193243,2004]
```

Each data belongs to one field

How can I put all single data into one field in a table?

summary(1).results gives me these as result which I want to store in a table
ans =

```
       1         114           3      170686        1990
       2          74          13     5668167        1997
```

Comment: I'm having a very hard time understanding your problem statement.  Do you have a single cell array, and in this cell array you have three fields - Each field has a single array?

Comment: If I do summary(1).results I get `ans =

           1         114           3      170686        1990
           2          74          13     5668167        1997` I want to store these data in 5 specific field.

Comment: There are 10 numbers. How should this be divided up? You're not meeting yourself clear. Please edit your post with an example of how this structure should look

Comment: Check the file. When you type summary.results(1:1502) its gives you the answer and I want the answer in a table https://www.dropbox.com/s/cn761vqrfm68d9o/movement2.mat

Comment: one element is a cell array 2*5

Comment: I would like to request that you update your post with an example of what you want done.  No code required... just an illustration (text / picture / etc.) of what you want done.  I know you want a table, but I don't know how this table is structured, or what the headers are for each column.  Until you do this, I (or probably no one else) will help you answer this question.

Comment: _yourQ_: "How can I put all single data into one field in a table?" _mineQ_: Which is your single data? Which are your  fields and what is the correlation of your single data and your fields?Place a hand made example for a singe data as you said and your fields!

Comment: for the first data [1,114,3,170686,1990;2,74,13,5668167,1997] it has 2 row which is separated with ; 1 is field 1, 114 is field 2, 3 is field 3, 170686 is field 4 and finally 1990 is field 5.....when you write summary(1).results....it gives you the answer as shown on the top.. it returns you two row....I just want to store all that in a table to import to excel @Darkmoor

Answer (score 0):

Use the function [cell2table](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2table.html)

Example:

```
T = cell2table(C)
```

Example with variable names:

```
T = cell2table(C,...
    'VariableNames',{'Age' 'FavoriteFood' 'Calories' 'NutritionGrade'})
```

Comment: C must be 2-D cell array!

Comment: give a while.. will figure out for you.

Comment: Convert your struct to cell first using this command: c = struct2cell(s), then use the above command..